# What done-ness is safe, but still juicy, to order wild boar cooked to?

Tags: food-safety, temperature, pork, game

I recently went to a restaurant here that claims to offer local fair. It was in a super touristy area so I have my doubts, but it plays the part well.

Anyway, what I ordered was the [Shogun Farms Wild Boar](https://shogunfarms.com/) loin, though I can't remember how it was cooked, but I think it was either on a grill or seared. However, I have always been told that you have to cook pork to well done or you will get parasites and die. And I learned from watching ***Monsters Inside Me*** on Animal Planet that you should cook wild game well done or you will get parasites and your life will suck. So basically, I ordered my wild pork game pork well done so I wouldn't get parasites and have my life suck until I die.

Now. The food was excellent. Even the boar loin. However, to paraphrase the famous Canadian food critic Squirrely Dan, it was drier than a fart. So my question is: at what done-ness should/could I have ordered this at such that it would have been juicy and delicious and I wouldn't get eye worms, trichinosis, or that thing where your skin will be itchy forever?

Addendum: I will accept answers that state that loin, due to its low fat, and boar, due to its lower fat, basically has to be cardboard to be safe. I will then at least be able to make an informed decision.

Answer (score 3):

The linked website says the animals are trapped, dewormed, deloused and checked for other problems. As this is a USDA approved farm (according to their website), they will have to follow USDA rules around parasites etc. This also means that the [USDA food safety rules apply](https://www.usda.gov/media/blog/2011/05/25/cooking-meat-check-new-recommended-temperatures). To quote the USDA:

> Cooking Whole Cuts of Pork: USDA has lowered the recommended safe cooking temperature for whole cuts of pork from 160 ºF to 145 ºF with the addition of a three-minute rest time. Cook pork, roasts, and chops to 145 ºF as measured with a food thermometer before removing meat from the heat source, with a three-minute rest time before carving or consuming. This will result in a product that is both safe and at its best quality—juicy and tender.

The company also states:

> The hogs are contained on our USDA state approved property where they are cared for daily by our trained and professional staff.

This means, that they aren't actually wild, at best this would be considered  free-range. From the photos on the website these aren't actually wild boar (*[Sus scrofa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_boar)*), simply free-range pigs (*[Sus domestica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestic_pig)*), possibly bordering on feral pigs (though daily tending doesn't indicate this at all), but still a completely different species.

Answer (score 3):

In 2011, the FDA has lowered the minimum recommended cooking temperature for pork. Previously, many folks considered the FDA safe temperature (previously 160°F) to be "overcooked."

[According to the FDA](https://www.fda.gov/food/people-risk-foodborne-illness/meat-poultry-seafood-food-safety-moms-be), the internal temperature at the center should be 145°F:

> Cook beef, pork, veal, and lamb roasts, steaks, and chops to at least 145° F (63° C), with a 3 minute rest time.

145°F generally falls into the colloquial category of ordering a meat cooked to "medium" at a restaurant. However, good safety is always based on temperature. Despite the FDA's prior recommendations being a much higher temperature, 145°F is still a sufficient cooking temperature to kill the parasite that causes trichinosis.

From [another article](https://honest-food.net/on-trichinosis-in-wild-game/), specifically addressing parasites and wild boar:

> According to a Centers for Disease Control study that surveyed incidence of the disease from 2008 to 2012, there were only 84 cases of trichinosis in all of America. Of those, 43 were eating wild game. That’s 43 people in a five-year period, and 30 of those 43 were in one incident, an unfortunate party
>
> ...
>
> The actual temperature that kills the trichinella parasite is 137°F, which happens to be medium-rare. But be forewarned: Every iota of meat must hit that temperature to kill the parasite

Comment: it's easy to ensure all the meat has reached the safe temperature with sous vide

Comment: The reason why they were able to lower from their previous recommendations is because hogs used to be fed any leftovers, scraps, trash, etc, and there would be problems with parasites, especially trichinosis. The Swine Protection Act, passed in 1980, required that any human food scraps that came in contact or had meat had to be cooked at boiling temps (212F/100C) for at least 30 minutes. With that requirement, there no longer needed to be cooking the meat, itself, as long to take care of parasites.  ***However***, with truly wild boar, one has no control over what the boar has been eating.

Comment: From the web site, it looks like these animals are not harvested from the wild, as much as initially captured, then managed/raised after that, so probably the lower standard is okay.

Answer (score 0):

actually trichinosis already is killed with  enough time at 52.4°C, so 55°C(131°F) for, depending on the cut 2-4 hours sous vide will be plenty to kill pretty much anything. in domestic pigs even freeing in a cold home freezer for a couple weeks is sufficient to prevent trichinosis, though pasteurization needs to be done anyway for other stuff, some of the trichinosis parasites in wild game are more cold resistant. 55°C is also here you've killed Salmonella. go 57°C to be extra safe. the reason the FDA states much higher numbers is that they assume the meat is removed from the heat once it reaches the temperature, only held there for a few minutes(resting with the heat of the meat around the core giving off heat)in which case you need significantly higher temps. 70-75°C/160.165°F are the instantly safe temperatures, good to keep uneducated people safe, bad for having a nice, juicy piece of meat.

PS: I think you were scared by sensationalist media, yeah, there are some nasty parasites, but it's not that easy to get, most restaurants wouldn't dare serve something that isn't 99.99% safe and even if you get the big bad trichinosis, he majority of cases are so mild people don't even notice, mortality rate is about 0.2%. now if you get a major infection it's gonna be nasty but the realistic worst case is your gonna be sick for a few days to weeks, then possibly take a few months till your back to 100% but that's what you can get from covid or even a really bad flu. I'm not telling you to eat raw wild game, definetly nor omnivores or carnivores but but it's not the horror show of suffering for the rest of your life you seem to expect, this are extremely rare, worst case scenarios in those shows, you could do the same thing about walking around in publi or doin' literally anything, there's always a risk, but you can decrease it to where it's pretty much negligable.